# wordpress wp-blog-header.php on line 16

Tags: wordpress

I have a site made in wordpress and from one moment to the next it does not work. You can not see the site as before, so I investigate and I get the following error.

error“Call to undefined function wp() in /home……..public_html/wp-blog-header.php on line 16”
how can i fix it?
regards

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

```
$wp_did_header = true;

// Load the WordPress library.
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

// Set up the WordPress query.
wp();

// Load the theme template.
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
```

}

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that file.  Something else is causing your problem.  Doing a clean reinstall of the WordPress core files might be the quickest and easiest fix.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I have managed to fix:

Take a look at the wp files inside the public_html folder and check if any of them have size 0.
Copy the content of public_html from other WordPress installation (same install version) and overwrite all the 0 sized files with files from that.

Comment: Bingo! I did this and found my wp-load.php file was empty. Just replaced it with a code from a fresh install and my site was up again.

Comment: It saves my day. @naudi_alvarado should mark this as the right answer if it servers you.

Answer (score 2):

**WHY this error comes?**
**Answer**: because of wp-load.php file empty if you check on the root folder.

**So the solution is.**

1. Change the file wp-load.php permission 644 to 444.
2. Then download the specific version of WordPress from here. https://wordpress.org/download/releases/ (for check your current WordPress version goto wp-includes/version.php) you can see your WordPress version.
3. Open the zip folder then copy the wp-load.php code and paste to empty file in your server

[image]

Comment: This always happens on NameCheap specifically.